# Fatal error: Call to undefined function oci_connet()

Tags: php, oracle, connection, oci8, instant

I continue to get a Fatal error: Call to undefined funciton oci_connet(). Cannot connect using PHP to oci8 with instant client to oracle 12c databade. Uninstalled apache, php and the instant client. Have reinstalled them still all. Made sure everything in PHP ini had been changed, http, etc. had the correct information. Checked path and system files to make sure instant client was placed where it is suppose to be.  Have followed guidelines form the Oracle website, PHP website, but still get the same error The server is Windows 2008 R2 that was installed with IIS. IIS was turned off so that we can use Apache and the fastcgi files. Not sure if it is a server configuration server configuration. The database sit on another server. Each piece PHP, Apache, the database all works independently but cannot connect together. SQL Developer works fine, but cannot get SQLPlus to connect
I have tried many suggestions on here but did not solve the problem.  I am going to place the instant client on the database server and try to see if I get a connection. Two days and another person is helping, but no solution. Any help/suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: This posts probably benefits from you reading [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enter_key)

Comment: Can you show the code that is responsible for the connection?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully the message is Call to undefined function oci_connect() (Note added c, or you have bigger problems)

Make sure you installed the correct version for PHP on the web server. If you have PHP 32 bit, make sure you installed 32 bit instant client. Likewise with PHP 64 bit, you need 64 bit Oracle instant client. It does not matter if your OS is 64 bit, if your PHP is 32 bit, the instant client must be 32 bit. Look for a message in your logs about an error loading oci.dll.